# Codeigniter unable to connect to MSSQL database

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, centos, cpanel

**In CodeIgniter** I have an error when trying to connect to mssql(remote connect) which is `Unable to connect to the database`, the error not appear every connect. It sometimes appears sometimes not

**That’s why I can't get data and my server slows down if connection problems repeatedly occur**

My connect configuration here,

```
$db['mssql'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'IP,port',
    'username' => '********',
    'password' => '********',
    'database' => '********',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

and an example query from the model;

```
public function getBanks($accountCode,$currency){
    $this->Mssql = $this->load->database('mssql',TRUE);
    $this->Mssql->select('AccountingCode,BankName,BranchCode,BranchName,IbanNo');
    $this->Mssql->from('Bank');
    $this->Mssql->where(array('AccountingCode'=>$accountCode,'Curr'=>$currency));
    return $this->Mssql->get()->result();
}
```

**server features:** `CodeIgniter 3.1` with whm/cpanel on centos VPS server.

**Remote Mssql:** Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3),

**Edit: sometimes query takes a long time or get a timeout. But Normally it takes 3-4 seconds. the long-time example below**

```
Uptime:  223 seconds
Executable: 
/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm
Command Line (often faked in exploits):
php-fpm: pool mydomian_com                         
Network connections by the process (if any):
tcp: centos:35097 -> mssql:1490
Files open by the process (if any):
/dev/null
/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea- 
php73/ci_session2c2f2a2567083e33da437a984c0c6171352aa8eb
```

Comment: FYI; SQL Server 2008(R2) is now completely unsupported and it is strongly recommended you upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: If it works sometimes but fails when you experience the server as slow, then it sounds like some server issue and not a PHP issue.

Comment: @Lamu ,I have no authority for this,@Magnus Eriksson , i think that the reason for the slowness is it can't get an answer during the connection

Answer (score 0):

If your database and web script are in same server, then you can keep localhost as the hostname..

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => "localhost",
'username' => "username",
'password' => "password",
'database' => "db_name",
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

Comment: mssql database is remote not in same server and db driver should be sqlsrv because database is sql server

Comment: If remote server, Keep  IP as hostname and In your database server set database server ip as bind-address.. Hope it will work